# Do we have to use the car daily, before the first one month service?

Tags: honda, service

I have bought a Honda Amaze 2018 a few days back. The sales person informed me that its first free service to be done after 1 month. I plan to use it not for daily commute but only on weekends. Some one told me to use the car daily atleast for the first one month, so that if any issues will surface on the first month service, or else they may go undetected if not used to the fullest. Is there truth in this claim?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to do this. While it's true that the more you drive the sooner you will discover some problems it's not worth the time and money. Remember that your car will be under warranty for much longer than 1 month, so if you discover a problem after 3 months they still have to fix it for you.